# New Contributor hover card information opens a scrollbar on a post

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tooltips, new-contributor-indicator

Not sure when this started happening, but the new contributor hover information now makes a scrollbar appear, and keeps all of the hover card information constrained to a small area surrounding the post.

Here's a gif representation, from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361441/622284):

[image: Hover card for new contributor now shows a scrollbar]

This appears to happen on every site I visit, so I assume it's network-wide.

I'm using Chrome version 88.0.4324.182 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10, if that matters.

Could this be looked into and fixed?

Comment: [Also reported on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405558/8967612).

Comment: @Spevacus I suspect this doesn't have anything to do with the particular browser you're using. I'm noticing the same issue with Microsoft Edge version 84.0.522.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah I figured I would include browser information in the unlikely event it was browser-specific, but as you pointed out that seems irrelevant. Thanks for testing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [change that introduced this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361439/377214) has been reverted.